# LED lights "popcorning" (flashing on and off randomly)

Tags: led

My church installed some recessed LEDs connected to a Chauvet DMX-4 dimmer pack. The pack is connected to an Elation stage setter dimmer console so we can control from our sound booth. When turned off, the lights begin to flash on randomly then immediately off then repeats continuely(popcorning).

Comment: What happens when you try it with incandescent bulbs?

Comment: The dimmer and bulbs aren’t compatible with each other.

Comment: Make and model of the LEDs? No-name or house-brand junkers from the big box store?

Answer (score 2):

Your dimmer and LED lights are incompatible.

In the off position the dimmer is leaking a small current to the lights, this is enough to charge the smoothing capacitors in the LED drivers, once charged to a sufficient threshold, the circuit is able to drive the LEDs and drain the capacitor and the process starts again.

See answers to other questions about [LED Blinking](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=LED%20blinking)

See

- [Dimming LED lamps with ordinary dimmers - Big Clive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWh2obSY0dQ)
- [How to FIX Flickering LED Lights & LED lights that won't Turn Off with Dimmer Switch - Vince](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfVkM8kuOl0)

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with your equipment so I am just going to make a generic statement. If the dimming equipment is using solid state relays to turn off electrical flow to your lighting, the main thing you have to know is that solid state relays never turn completely off. If your drivers to your LED's are not matched to your equipment, then what may be happening is your driver is getting some electrical flow. Since most drivers use a range of voltages, then your drivers are "getting confused" about the low voltage coming from you equipment and are trying to light up.

Your best bet is to try and get with the manufacturers tech support and see if they have a preferred or matched LED. Other than that you might install a mechanical switch that completely disconnects the power source for the circuit.

Hope this helps